# Android 5.0 API 21 application files contain AppCompat references

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design, android-5.0-lollipop

I am trying to learn well the structure of Android application sources. I created a new project in Android Studio. I want to use the latest features of the material design and at this point I don't think about compatibility with earlier Android versions. So I selected Minimum SDK - "API 21: Android 5.0 (Lollipop)". Then I selected "Fullscreen Activity". The first exception is "Rendering problems. The following classes could not be found: android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar" when I try to open activity_fullscreen.xml. In the build.gradle I removed two last lines from dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
}
```

Then I got a build error:

```
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
```

I configured the 'styles.xml' to use the Material theme instead of `"Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"`

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

But one error is still present:

```
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar'.
```

in the Action bar style definition

```
<style name="FullscreenActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/black_overlay</item>
</style>
```

I don't know how to set up action bar without support library. Why my project does need it at all? The documentation I read describes action bar setup only with AppCompat. Or Material theme does not provide action bar at all? Why appcompat-v7 references are present in the sources since I selected minimum SDK 21? I am really confused because I am not able to build even a simplest project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because Android Studio does not have different templates based on API level, it just uses AppCompat everywhere.

Replace `Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar` with `Widget.ActionBar` or even better, remove `FullscreenActionBarStyle` and all references to it and use the system default.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you removing the appcompat and design support library from dependencies?
This is the reason you are getting build error because

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar
```

and

```
Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar
```

are available in appcompat library.

Comment: Because as I described I want to use only the latest UI features provided by Android 5.0 Lollipop API 21 without providing any compatibility.